# What are the implications of a PSN account country?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I just bought a PS4, and want to purchase PS Plus for multiplayer gaming. I  read on the internet that you can't change the country of a PSN account after creating it.

What are the implications of choosing a country for the account? Will it affect the servers that will be chosen to play?

I'm in the US for sometime, then heading to Spain. I will play with friends from Spain. Which country to choose? US (so that I can use Netflix app) or Spain (where my friends are located)?

Answer (score 2):

It mainly affects what you are able to get from the online store and your payment options, there might be no release or censorship for certain games in some areas of the world, a lot of people create Japanese secondary accounts to access games not released in the US or Europe for example.
Also pay-pal used to be unavailable in for European PSN accounts while it worked fine for US accounts.

One other thing are the free games you get with a PSN-Plus subscription, those are bound to regions as well (different regions have different offerings).

You can play with your Spanish friends even if you have a US account there are no restrictions to this it only affects you when you play with strangers and even then you can specify multiple spoken languages in your account.
But there is no guarantee that Netflix is available in Spain even if you get a US account, they might block it based on your location.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who bought their PS3  before moving abroad, one concern that I had to work around was that you cannot add any funds to your account from a "foreign" payment card.  My workaround for this was to purchase gift cards from my original country.